# Custom Mobile Robot with ROS

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hye, for your information, im a new ROS user . my task in the university is to implement ROS in custom mobile robot. i already try the rosserial to connect arduino+ros+low level device. But i seems not clear about the different of ROS and another normal arduino mobile robot project. from my understanding, ROS is a operating system that can implement a multi task instruction in the same time. My task is to design a robot which is follow the line and avoid any obstacle at the same time. i use my notebook as a main processor for ROS and Arduino MEGA 2560 to control the sensors, motor and etc. i hope you will help me. thnks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29347/custom-mobile-robot-with-ros./) by [MyloXyloto](https://answers.ros.org/users/1877/myloxyloto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MyloXyloto](https://answers.ros.org/users/1877/myloxyloto/) on 2012-03-12**:
Thnks sir. i try to go trough with /cmd_vel . thnks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is intended to be run on computer hardware, like the notebook you indicated.  rosserial is intended to allow you to bridge physical hardware and sensors to the ROS computation graph using a micro controller (at this time, the Arduino has client libraries developed).  rosserial should be used when the hardware doesn't already have a ready-made interface and driver (for example, you shouldn't use a GPS receiver with rosserial).

**Example Subscriber**

For example, if you have a motor controller implemented on an Arduino, you will want to create a [ROS Subscriber](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World) that will listen to a [Twist Message](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) on a given topic.  Many people use `/cmd_vel` as the topic for this purpose.

Now, with a ROS core running, and the rosserial_python node running, you should see a `/cmd_vel` appear in a `rostopic list` command.  You can use another node on your system to publish messages to `/cmd_vel`, that the Arduino will interpret into motor commands.  The Arduino firmware should be able to turn a Twist message (linear and angular velocities) into appropriate motor commands for your platform.

**Example Publisher**

Another application may be reading an ultrasonic rangefinder.  You will physically interface the line sensor to your Arduino, and then create a [ROS Publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink).  You could make this message type a [Float32](http://ros.org/doc/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float32.html) if you wanted to represent a floating point distance or perhaps an [Int32](http://ros.org/doc/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int32.html), if you wanted to get the raw ADC values.  These would then be published into the computation graph on the topic of your choice (say `/rangefinder`).  You could then see these values by doing `rostopic echo /rangefinder` on the command line.

You can get a better idea of the capabilities of rosserial on the [rosserial tutorials page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial/Tutorials).

**Putting it all together**

Now, if your robot can receive movement commands from ROS via `/cmd_vel` and can broadcast readings of the physical world, then you can start creating (or using) other ROS nodes to process this data and make decisions.

For example, if your robot can accept command velocities, can publish range scans, and can publish odometry information, you can start to use higher-level nodes for navigation, localization, and path planning.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11